# Scroll to specific div on click, after applying a jQuery filter on portfolio items

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building a website and I've accomplished to be able to filter my portfolio/projects with a click on a link in a sidebar (with a little help).

Now I would like the page to scroll down to the specific projects div after/or while this filter is being applied.

I'm using the following code for the filtering:

```
jQuery('#mk-filter-portfolio li a[data-filter="'+portfolio_category+'"]').click(); 
});
```

And i would like to use something simple like this for scrolling down:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#projects").offset().top
}, 2000);
});
```

Could you guys please help me combine the two to something functional? Or offer a better solution?

Thanks!